# Determining cpu architecture at runtime linux?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I want to detect the CPU architecture at runtime in a Linux environment, I've looked at `getauxval(AT_PLATFORM)` but sadly it's not portable since it's relatively new. Would there be an alternative to `getauxval(AT_PLATFORM)`? I could parse `/proc/cpuinfo` but figured that there might be an easier way. I'm trying to get output similar to `uname -m`.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What are you going to do with the resulting information?

Comment: By "CPU architecture" you mean whether it's 32- or 64-bit, right? Not whether it's x86 vs ARM vs PowerPC?

Comment: @Botje I'm executing an instruction which isn't present in i386 but is present from i486 onward. Hence i want to determine the architecture at runtime and if it's i386 skip over that instruction.

Comment: @Jorengarenar I would like to get the whole arch, x86-64, i386, arm7....

Comment: What kind of archaic hardware are you planning to run your software on?

Comment: Just would like the program to be portable from i386 - x86-64, so trying to make best efforts to make it works on as much CPU's as possible.

Comment: @Jorengarenar The CPUID instruction

Comment: I would parse `/proc/cpuinfo` personally.

Comment: Could you please edit question and make a choice by removing the tag: C or C++? Different languages...

Comment: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html Just found this, conforms to POSIX 2001 so should be relatively portable! Thanks for the recommendations guys

Comment: @kebs Sorry thought I'd tag C++ guys too because they also deal with syscalls

Answer (score 4):

```
I'm trying to get output similar to uname -m.
```

Why not look at how `uname` does it? Run `apt source coreutils` and in `src/uname.c`:

```
...
while ((c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "asnrvmpio",
                        uname_long_options, NULL)) != -1)
...

case 'm':
    toprint |= PRINT_MACHINE;
```

and

```
if (uname (&name) == -1)
...
if (toprint & PRINT_MACHINE)
        print_element (name.machine);
```

(notice the usage of the `uname` function).

---

`uname` is a syscall defined by POSIX and wrapped in glibc:

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>
int uname(struct utsname *buf);
```

and will store the machine hardware identifier in `buf->machine`, which is what's printed by `uname -m`.

As an aside - in `lib/uname.c` you can see coreutils' implementation of a custom `uname` function for Windows systems (which don't support the `uname` syscall). This implementation uses the `GetVersionEx` and `GetSystemInfo` WinAPIs which provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a program that has to be built on different architectures, and needs a build system that specifies different code for different architectures, it would be simple to add some defined constant that allows you to evaluate in which system it has been built and check that constant inside the program.

On the contrary, if your program is portable enough to be built without any change on different (most) architectures, you'll probably will not need to know in which of these architectures it has been built.

This was probably the schema followed historically to address the problem.  I don't think you can solve this in a portable way, if your program can be built in non-linux system (e.g. BSD or QNX)